# Passsar função pela função de validação em php

Tags: php, funções, validação, parâmetros

Boas, eu tenho uma classe "Entidade", onde tenho a propriedade "Telefone", para o telefone, tenho uma função a parte que valida o número de telefone "isvalidTelefone", tenho tambem uma função que faz print de todas as propriedades...
A minha duvida é de iniciante..
Como faço para ao inves de ele fazer echo do numero de telefone simplesmente, façla print do numero de telefone passando pela validação do "isvalid"?

Aqui está o meu código:

GETTER E SETTER:

```
public function getTelefone() {
    return $this->telefone;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $telefone
 */
public function setTelefone($telefone) {
    if ($telefone === $this->isvalidTelefone($telefone)) {
        echo "este numero esta errado";
    } else {
        echo "este numero esta certo";
    }
}
```

FUNÇÃO DE VALIDAÇÃO:

```
public function isvalidTelefone($telefone) {
    if ((strlen($telefone) < 9) || (strlen($telefone) > 9)) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ PRINT DAS PROPRIEDADES:

```
public function printEntidade() {
    return $this->nome . '<br>' .
            $this->email . '<br>' .
            $this->nif . '<br>' .
            $this->codpostal . '<br>' .
            $this->localidade . '<br>' .
            $this->morada . '<br>' .
            $this->pais . '<br>' .
            $this->telefone . '<br>' .
            $this->saldo;
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Opa Nelson, você quer que só imprima o número do telefone se o mesmo for válido?

Comment: Olá Andre, sim é isso, eu quero que imprima se o numero for válido, ou seja, quero que no setTelefone tenha a função de validação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro valide no `setTelefone` e só atribua o valor caso o `isValidTelefone` seja `true`, veja abaixo:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $telefone
 */
public function setTelefone($telefone)
{
    if($this->isvalidTelefone($telefone))
    {
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }
}
```

Após isso você pode colocar um ternário na função `printEntidade` verificando se o `$this->email` e concatenando caso o mesmo exista, veja abaixo:

```
public function printEntidade()
{
    return $this->nome . '<br>' .
        $this->email . '<br>' .
        $this->nif . '<br>' .
        $this->codpostal . '<br>' .
        $this->localidade . '<br>' .
        $this->morada . '<br>' .
        $this->pais . '<br>' .
        (isset($this->telefone) ? $this->telefone . '<br>' : '') .
        $this->saldo;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Era isto que estava procurando!

Comment: Mais uma coisa...
eu tenho tamém um "setSaldo", onde tenho o seguinte:
    public function setSaldo($saldo)
    {
        return '<br>' . '€' . number_format($saldo, 2);
    }


Como faço o print do saldo com o simbolo do euro como está ai no setSaldo?

Comment: A função set não tem o objetivo de retornar algo, tem como função setar um atributo. Faça da seguinte maneira: public function setSaldo($saldo) { $this->saldo= '€' . number_format($saldo, 2); }

Comment: Muito bom, muito obrigado pela ajuda André, aprendi muito!